# Data import for bar charts on R

Tags: r, bar-chart, export-to-csv

Hi I am an absolute novice on R and I am trying to make bar charts from an excel file.

My data includes three groups of cells and their % of a certain protein and their MFI.
I wanted to compare the values of each cell type side by side for both the % and MFI (like three pairs of bars, one for each cell type) I am not explaining great I am sorry!.

I have Tidyverse and ggplot2, I would like to know how to format this data table and make charts with both variables in one block
Also if I could add colours to each of the bar pairs?

I would appreciate any guidance greatly :p

Should I rearrange the[data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1qrU.png) to be cell types as columns and their MFI and % as rows?

dput results:
[image version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G89HN.png)

> dput(csv_ICS)

Text:
structure(list(ICS = c("WT negative control", "WT", "CD8-HLA-E negative control",
"CD8-HLA-E", "CD8-HLA-F negative control", "CD8-HLA-F"), `% CD8` = c(0.012,
0.11, 0.025, 14, 0.075, 3.14), `MFI CD8` = c(850, 2341, 828,
4040, 803, 2672), `% Myc` = c(0.012, 1.46, 0, 3.85, 0.012, 1.61
), `MFI Myc` = c(6165, 11407, 6397, 14860, 6056, 12021), `% HLA-A,B,C` = c(0.67,
99.3, 1.82, 99.2, 1.15, 99.4), `MFI HLA-A,B,C` = c(5716, 62177,
6042, 65998, 5664, 63194)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

Comment: hi Luna! Welcome to StackOverflow! Would you be able to run `dput()` on the data table, and copy paste the results into your question? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @ L V N Λ, the percentages and MFI values cover very different ranges. How were you envisioning the y-axis scale would look?

Comment: Is this summarized data? It looks like each row contains the means of each value for each group. You could certainly plot these as bars with geom_bar() or geom_col(), but ideally we would have the individual observations/replicates for each group so that you could include error bars, which is practically expected for bar plots for flow data. I would make each row an observation, and include a sample column and a group column.